# Unable to get Google Drive file parents using API key

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-apis-explorer, google-drive-shared-drive

I am trying to move Google Drive file (Google Sheet/Google Document) from Shared Team Drive to another Shared Drive but my Service account is failing to get file filed parents from v3.

**I've tested with the Playground and noticed that "parents" field is only returned when you are Authenticated with Google OAuth 2.0 BUT NOT when you are using API Key (or in my case Service auth file).**

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get

[parents screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xc9kl.png)

[no parents screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLjpf.png)

Working fine with My Drive but not when returning parents for Shared Drive files.

```
 // My Google Client is initialised
 const googleClient = new google.auth.JWT(
   privatekey.client_email,
   null,
   privatekey.private_key,
   ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
     'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
     'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']
 );

 // Google Drive v3
 const googleDrive = google.drive({
   version: 'v3',
   auth: googleClient
 });

 // Getting File details
 const file = googleDrive.files.get({
   fileId,
   fields: '*',
   supportsTeamDrives: true
 });
```

Can you help me with any ideas or explain me the difference in the API responses?

Answer (score 0):

API Keys get their permissions based on the project permission (and other settings on the Cloud Console).

OAuth authenticates as the current user and is able to access the APIs as that user would.

You can read more about that [here](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/when-why-api-key).

In this case, the Try It Feature does not have an API key able to access the methods you are trying to execute.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks ZektorH, I think you are write about the Try It Feature but my problem was related to my Service account as well. When trying to get parents from a Google file within a Shared Drive you need your service to be part of the Shared Drive members (I was trying with just shared with the Service account file :().

Comment: Hello @GeorgiGeorgiev, If you are using a Service Account to access your Drive Files, you need to have read-access to them. Even if a service account is supposed to impersonate you, it cannot see files it doesn't have rights to. In this case, add the permissions necessary for the email of your service account.